# Oracle exception handler buggy?

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql

I even posted in Steven Feuersteins blog on this:

http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2017/02/now-not-to-handle-exceptions.html

If in Oracle (12.2 onward) a statement executes sequentially or parallel will change the caught error in PL/SQL. The following script will show the misbehavior and I consider this as a bug! But I would ask for a proper workaround for this, any suggestions appreciated.

Just an easy example, sequential index rebuild will raise:

```
ORA-01452: cannot CREATE UNIQUE INDEX; duplicate keys found
```

While the very same executed in parallel will do:

```
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server
```

More details below:

```
drop table t_tst;
create table t_tst (a number not null);

insert into t_tst select level from dual connect by level <= 1000000;
commit;

insert into t_tst select level from dual connect by level <= 1000000;
commit;

alter session disable parallel ddl;
create unique index x_tst on t_tst(a) unusable;

declare
    e_pproc            EXCEPTION;
    e_div0             EXCEPTION;
    e_uniq             EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(e_pproc, -12801);
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(e_div0, -1476);
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(e_uniq, -01452);
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('dynamic SQL - rebuild unique index sequential');
    execute immediate 'alter index x_tst rebuild';
exception
    when e_div0 then
        dbms_output.put_line('catch div0');
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode);
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
        dbms_output.put_line(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
    when e_uniq then
        dbms_output.put_line('catch uniq');
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode);
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
        dbms_output.put_line(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('catch others');
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode);
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
        dbms_output.put_line(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
end;
/

alter session force parallel ddl;

declare
    e_pproc            EXCEPTION;
    e_div0             EXCEPTION;
    e_uniq             EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(e_pproc, -12801);
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(e_div0, -1476);
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(e_uniq, -01452);
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('dynamic SQL - rebuild unique index parallel');
    execute immediate 'alter index x_tst rebuild';
exception
    when e_div0 then
        dbms_output.put_line('catch div0');
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode);
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
        dbms_output.put_line(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
    when e_uniq then
        dbms_output.put_line('catch uniq');
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode);
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
        dbms_output.put_line(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('catch others');
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode);
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
        dbms_output.put_line(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
end;
/

drop index x_tst;
alter session disable parallel dml;

declare
    e_pproc            EXCEPTION;
    e_div0             EXCEPTION;
    e_uniq             EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(e_pproc, -12801);
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(e_div0, -1476);
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(e_uniq, -01452);
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('dynamic SQL - insert with div 0 sequential');
    execute immediate 'insert into t_tst select 123456 / (a-1) from t_tst';
exception
    when e_div0 then
        dbms_output.put_line('catch div0');
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode);
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
        dbms_output.put_line(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
    when e_uniq then
        dbms_output.put_line('catch uniq');
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode);
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
        dbms_output.put_line(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('catch others');
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode);
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
        dbms_output.put_line(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
end;
/

alter session force parallel query;
alter session force parallel dml;

declare
    e_pproc            EXCEPTION;
    e_div0             EXCEPTION;
    e_uniq             EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(e_pproc, -12801);
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(e_div0, -1476);
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(e_uniq, -01452);
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('dynamic SQL - insert with div 0 parallel');
    execute immediate 'insert into t_tst select 123456 / (a-1) from t_tst';
exception
    when e_div0 then
        dbms_output.put_line('catch div0');
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode);
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
        dbms_output.put_line(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
    when e_uniq then
        dbms_output.put_line('catch uniq');
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode);
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
        dbms_output.put_line(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('catch others');
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode);
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
        dbms_output.put_line(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
end;
/

declare
    e_pproc            EXCEPTION;
    e_div0             EXCEPTION;
    e_uniq             EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(e_pproc, -12801);
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(e_div0, -1476);
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(e_uniq, -01452);
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('none dynamic - insert with div 0 parallel');
    insert into t_tst select 123456 / (a-1) from t_tst;
exception
    when e_div0 then
        dbms_output.put_line('catch div0');
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode);
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
        dbms_output.put_line(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
    when e_uniq then
        dbms_output.put_line('catch uniq');
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode);
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
        dbms_output.put_line(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('catch others');
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode);
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
        dbms_output.put_line(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
end;
/
```

Just adding the result for convenience:

```
dynamic SQL - rebuild unique index sequential
catch uniq
-1452
ORA-01452: cannot CREATE UNIQUE INDEX; duplicate keys found
ORA-01452: cannot CREATE UNIQUE INDEX; duplicate keys found



dynamic SQL - rebuild unique index parallel
catch others
-12801
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P00P, instance vpdm4525db01.dyndb.itoper.local:PCDB0020_45251 (1)
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P00P, instance vpdm4525db01.dyndb.itoper.local:PCDB0020_45251 (1)
ORA-01452: cannot CREATE UNIQUE INDEX; duplicate keys found




dynamic SQL - insert with div 0 sequential
catch div0
-1476
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero




dynamic SQL - insert with div 0 parallel
catch others
-12801
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P00Y, instance vpdm4525db01.dyndb.itoper.local:PCDB0020_45251 (1)
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P00Y, instance vpdm4525db01.dyndb.itoper.local:PCDB0020_45251 (1)
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero


none dynamic - insert with div 0 parallel
catch others
-12801
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P00P, instance vpdm4525db01.dyndb.itoper.local:PCDB0020_45251 (1)
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P00P, instance vpdm4525db01.dyndb.itoper.local:PCDB0020_45251 (1)
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what your expected output should be and why you think there is a bug. You have a wall of code but no explanation of where exactly the issue is, what is being changed and what we should be looking to solve; so please help us to help you and make it simple for us to understand the problem and not have to wade through the source code and the output and try to guess which part of the output is wrong.

Comment: If it would make it easier for us to understand you could split each anonymous PL/SQL block into its own code block and put its output immediately afterwards with commentary on whether that block is correct or incorrect and why (rather than having one huge chunk of code and then a huge chunk of output with immediate no correlation between them which means we need to keep scrolling up and down and try to keep the program and output states in our memory as we look for problems).

Comment: "*and I consider this as a bug!*" - then create an issue with the Oracle support

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug. If you look at the error description, you'll find this:

```
12801, 00000, "error signaled in parallel query server %s"
// *Cause: A parallel query server reached an exception condition.
// *Action: Check the following error message for the cause, and consult
//          your error manual for the appropriate action.
// *Comment: This error can be turned off with event 10397, in which
//           case the server's actual error is signaled instead.
```

So, trying your code, when I set this event, I get this:

```
dynamic SQL - rebuild unique index parallel
catch uniq
-1452
ORA-01452: cannot CREATE UNIQUE INDEX; duplicate keys found
ORA-01452: cannot CREATE UNIQUE INDEX; duplicate keys found
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for pointing this, missed it completely. Still the result is kind of inconsistent, would you agree? In some cases, you get both errors in the message, in some cases only ORA-12801.

Comment: I did not check all the cases you pointed. If you do not disable via the event, then you'll get the 2 errors, and depending on the tool, you may or may not see both. If the tool displays all the error stack, which is usually the case, you'll get both, otherwise, you may just see the 12801.